# java how to add variables to an object from a string

Tags: java, string, loops

I have two objects that are being stored in arrays:

```
Game(String creator, String title, int releaseYear, int NumberSold)  
Creator(String name, String gamesWorkedOn)
```

`Game(creator)` has multiple creators, so is stored as a string like this: `"creator1, creator2, creator3"` using commas to separate their values.

Not all games have multiple creators and there are not many different creators in total.

What I am trying to do is loop through an array of `Game(games)` and extract a creator variable from it and assign it to the `Creator(name)` and then match any games that creator is mentioned in and assign those title variables to `Creator(gamesWorkedOn)`.

So far I have this:

```
public static void PopulateCreators(ArrayList<Game> games) {
    //populating an array of Creators with games they have worked on
    boolean match = false;
    String thisCreator;
    String gamesWorkedOn;

    ArrayList<Creator> creatorArray = new ArrayList<Creator>();

    for (int i = 0; i < games.size(); i++) {
    thisCreator = games.get(i).getGameCreator();
    thisCreator = thisCreator.replaceAll(", ",  "\n");
```

Which gives me this output using a sysout:

```
Shigeru Miyamoto
Satoshi Tajiri
Yoshiaki Koizumi
Koichi Hayashida
Shigeru Miyamoto
```

My desired output would be to have something like this:

```
name = "Shigeru Miyamoto"
gamesWorkedOn = "game1, game2, game3"
```

I am looking at using a for loop but am unsure on how to implement it here.

Edit:

I forgot to mention a couple of details that I didn't think were important but I will be a bit clearer now. This is a Swing based project I am working on that takes user inputs and stores these arrays which are then saved into a JSON file that is read upon loading of the application and when a user clicks a 'save' button.

Comment: Why are you working with Strings at all if you already have existing classes? Why doesn't the Game class have a `Creator creator` or `List<Creator> creators` instead of `String creator` and why doesn't the Creator have a `List<Game> gamesWorkedOn` instead of `String gamesWorkedOn`? Saving those attributes as Strings and constantly converting them to the actual classes isn't really good design.

Comment: It seems you need to read up on object-oriented design...

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I think the reason I chose to do this was because at the time it was the easiest way for me to handle these strings in order to save to a JSON file (something I should have mentioned in the post). The creator class was made by myself last minute since I had not anticipated needing it. At the moment I have Games working perfectly that store in a JSON file and can be loaded into my Swing project without issue (albeit with bad design).

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want to do is map the creators to all the games that they have created or helped create. I'm going to start by creating a simplified version of the problem.

You have a list of:

```
    class Game {
        Set<Creator> creators;
    }
```

which you want to convert to:

```
    Map<Creator, Set<Game>> createdGames; // Map of creator name to games created
```

The first thing to do here is to find all of the unique creators to start adding to the map. This can be done with the stream API.

```
    createdGames = gameList.stream().flatMap(game -> game.creators.stream()).distinct().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> new HashSet<>()));
```

Now you can just loop through all the games again and add the game to a creator's set if they took part in the creation of that game.

```
    for(Game game : gameList) {
        for(Creator creator : createdGames.keySet()) {
            if(game.creators.contains(creator)) {
                createdGames.get(creator).add(game);
            }
        }
    }
```